# Is there any useful Android app for security assessments?

Tags: android, vulnerability-scanners, audit

I've been thinking for a while about whether or not ask this, as it may be a opinion-based question, but as I have seen a couple of non-closed questions about recommended books, so I think this is the same case.

Is there any app for Android which be useful during a security assessment?

Comment: "I have seen a couple of non-closed questions about recommended books" In general, those are old questions during the site's infancy where the rules are less strict. Nowadays, such questions would be considered "product recommendation" questions and I have voted to close this as such. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dSploit is great and packs tons of features and has wrappers for nmap (and other tools like hydra) and can also search the national vulnerability database. It also has many MITM attacks and login crackers(hydra). But its not available on the Play Store though. But APK can be downloaded [here](http://dsploit.net)

Another tool worth mentioning is Interceptor-ng. Which is basically like/is wireshark for your Android device. Its available on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=su.sniff.cepter&hl=en)

Network Discovery is also pretty good and light; and can scan for hosts and open ports. Its available on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.lamatricexiste.network&hl=en).

G-Mon is a powerful wardriving scanner and GSM / CDMA / EVDO / UMTS and LTE Netmonitor. And is great for scoping out access points. Its available on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.carknue.gmon2).

WiFiKill is a "wifi jammer"/DoS tool which can deauthenticate an entire network (you need to be connected to it; just in case your wondering) or a single device. Its not available on the Play Store but can be downloaded [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282900).

Special Mention:
bcmon is a tool(experimental) which allows monitor mode on Android devices which has the Broadcom chipset. I've never used this tool and hence can't offer much of an opinion on it. More info can be found [here.](https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/)

Good Luck.

Comment: I had tried dSploit time ago, but it was quite unstable performing some tasks and also I didn't like it wasn't on the store.  Gonna try the ones available on the store, specially G-Mon. I used Wifi Analyzer for wardriving.